# man is using system installtion of less, ignoring PATH

Tags: manpage

On my machine, I have the latest version of `less` installed through homebrew.
Around the time me updating to macOS 14, I noticed my `man` stopped loading less in the latest version. If I run `man man` and hit `V` to show the less version, I get `less 581.2`, which is the system installation of `less`. But if I export `MANPAGER` to `less`, and then re-run the previous steps, I get `less 643`. If I unexport `MANPAGER` and open up another man page and run in less `! echo $PATH` I see the expected output and that the location of brew installed less ahead of `/usr/bin/less`. So I can conclude that my `PATH` is properly passed to `man` but it's choosing to use `/usr/bin/less` anyway.

I know I can fix this by just exporting `MANPAGER` to `less`, but I never needed this before. This seems really fishy and I'm worried something more pernicious is going on.

Has anyone else run into this problem? What's causing my `man` to use the system installation of less?

Answer (score 0):

No idea what your `man man` prints, but mine does not tell `less` but `pager`, so given `less` is in `PATH` at the expected location, but `pager` not (and if I get your question right), then it could make sense that `PATH` appears non-working from the user-facing side, but it is actually the expectation of the command name from the inside that is not matched.

So while `less` is used as `pager` it is `pager` no `less`.

Therefore only changing the `PATH` for `less` does not suffice for `man(1)` which is looking for `pager`, which `PATH` was not changed for.

```bash
echo "$PATH"
command -v pager
command -v less
man pager
```

Furthermore with your question, and if we're still on the same page, you may want to provide feedback to the homebrew formula authors about your learning and discuss a useful default setting — given `man pager` actually shows `less(1)` on your box.

Until then, you could temporarily create a directory entry named `pager` as a symbolic link of `less` in the same directory that is in `PATH` of your homebrew'ed `less` override and see if it works. This could also work as your proof of concept for any further discussions with the formulas team since at the end of the day this is a programming question, right? Therefore such or other changes need to be filed upstream.

Comment: My `man man` says
`MANPAGER        
Program used to display files.
If unset, and color support is enabled, “less -sR” is used.
If unset, and color support is disabled, then PAGER is used.  If that has no value either, “less -s” is used.`

So why isn't `less -s` using PATH?

Comment: I also don't even have a `PAGER` environment variabled defined or a `pager` command on my `PATH`

Answer (score 0):

`man` defines its pager during the `./configure` stage before compilation:

```bash
MAN_CHECK_PROGS(pager, PAGER, use PAGER as default pager, pager less more)

printf "%s\n" "#define PROG_PAGER \"$pager\"" >>confdefs.h
```

This means that you are left off with using environment variables, which is perfectly fine, this was designed this way.

Comment: Very reasonable explanation, and thinking for the last sentence: They actually use environment variables never the less, it is just the parameter that is different: PATH or MANPAGER. And truly this is perfectly fine.

Comment: Hi, I don't have `PAGER` as en environment variable nor `pager` on my path. So are you saying that it just uses the `less` that was available at the time of the compile? And could you link to that snippet please?

Comment: The snippet is is the answer. `MAN_CHECK_PROGS` is a wrapper for an m4 macro `AC_CHECK_PROGS`, which tries and finds programs in path by their names, and this is in configure.ac file.